# How to connect node.js backend to NGINX reverse proxy server

Tags: node.js, nginx

I know I'm close but I can't seem to connect my `node.js` app to my `NGINX` reverse proxy.  My node app works locally and my config file tests ok.  It doesn't connect after it's been uploaded to Digital Ocean.

The error is **502 Bad Gateway**.

Something is missing and after a couple of hours of googling and testing I still can't find the problem.  Thanks so much for any help in advance!

These are the relevant lines from my `nginx.conf` file.

```js
 server {
        listen        80;
        listen        [::]:80;
        server_name   myDomainName.com;
        root          /www/html;

        location / {
             index       index.html;
        }

        location /proxytest {
            proxy_pass "http://www.myDomainName.com:8080";
        }

    }
```

This is my `node.js` test app.

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Server is up on port 8080');
});
```

Comment: you should probably `proxy pass` to the loopback address where your node app will be listening: `proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8080";`

Comment: Thanks Daniel I've tried that and it still doesn't work.  Dang.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: 502 bad gateway

Comment: does `curl 127.0.0.1:8080` return anything?

Comment: curl returns this.  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /</pre>
</body>
</html>

Comment: is this helps https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html